# A href tag is not working

Tags: php, html

Strange thing happens, I have this code, on my wordpress site:

```
    <a href="www.google.com" target="_self" class="facebook" ><img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/facebook.png"/></a>
```

The image is loaded, but is not clickable, I mean nothing happens when I click on it, what's wrong?

The link to my page is: http://toibz.com/ibz.  Click on the "facebook" logo in the lower right corner.

Comment: add http:// `<a href="http://www.google.com"..`

Comment: Do you get any errors in the browser console similar to `Refused to display document because display forbidden by X-Frame-Options.`?

Comment: @mgraph or just `//`, as in `<a href="//www.google.com"...`

Comment: A missing `http://` would not cause this issue. `www.google.com` is still a perfectly valid value.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Critocea. When you ask a question like this, it'll be helpful to give some more context; have you tried with plain text instead of an image? Can we see an example of what the rest of the page looks like? Lots of people use JSFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/) for sharing code examples.

Comment: The final HTML is more important as to what is going wrong since the lack of clickability is to do with the client proccessing the HTML sent by the php server after it has parsed everything...

Comment: @animuson: `www.google.com` is a valid link, but it won't load google.  It'll load `http://yoursite.com/www.google.com`.

Comment: @Rocket: Doesn't matter. It's still valid and *wouldn't* cause the issue described by the OP. It's just a side note.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL: `X-Frame-Options` is my guess.  When I try to make a link to Google in jsFiddle, nothing happens.  http://jsfiddle.net/vyXpk/

Comment: @Rocket: Strange. When I try it I get "This content cannot be displayed in a frame" (IE) or it just blanks out the frame (FF). This may not be desired behaviour but again its different from "nothing happens". I have since tested chrome for which "nothing happens" is an apt description so it might be easy to test this if the OP has a non-chrome browser to test in.

Comment: @Chris: It seems Google can say "don't show our site in a frame" and browsers respect its wishes.

Comment: @Rocket: Yeah, that isn't something I've come across before. I will say that I think IE handles this best though by actually telling you what is happening unlike chrome (which seems to just pretend you didn't click) or FF (which makes it clear you clicked but not clear why something went wrong). My last comment is badly phrased because I tested chrome and added the last bit after deciding that I couldn't replicate the original behaviour. :)

Comment: I've tried to add http  to change the target and try in different browser but the same result. I can't post to jsfiddle because It's a wordrpess site, here is the [link](http://toibz.com/ibz), the image is on the bottom right(facebook)

Answer (score 2):

add **http://** to your link like:

```
 <a href="http://www.google.com"..
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `position:fixed` on the a tag instead of floating it.

Comment: It works now,thank you,  but why do I have to add position: fixed?